# Radius of Ag+ and K+

Tags: electronic-configuration

According to the database of ionic radius

[Database of ionic radius](http://abulafia.mt.ic.ac.uk/shannon/ptable.php)

The ionic radius of silver(I) cation is totally smaller than potassium(I), regardless of their coordination number.

It seems quite contradictory to me as potassium(I) possesses argon electron configuration which is in third shell. While silver(I) valent electron belong to the fourth shell

What is probably the reason for this issue?

Comment: You have forgotten to consider the electron cloud contraction along each period.

Comment: I wonder if the contraction is so powerful to acquire such decrease in radius while considering 4s and 4p electron shielding effect.

Comment: it is very powerful. Search for periodic table with displayed atomic or ionic radii. See figure 4.5.2 at https://pressbooks.online.ucf.edu/chemistryfundamentals/chapter/libreaclone-ionic-radii-and-isoelectronic-series/